# rosparam load into shell script

Tags: navigation, shell, rosparam, script, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to run move_stack from the binary. So what i am actually trying to do is to load the parameters into a shell script. The shell script looks like this:

`#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "Executing Move_base"

rosparam load -v ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/costmap_common_params.yaml /global_costamap

rosparam load -v ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/costmap_common_params.yaml /local_costamap

rosparam load -v ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/base_global_planner_params.yaml
rosparam load -v

~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/base_local_planner_params.yaml

rosparam load -v ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/global_costmap_params.yaml

rosparam load -v ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa/local_costmap_params.yaml

cd ~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/move_base/bin/

./move_base home/kostasof/Desktop/test_t420/Move_Base.xml wlan0`

As you can see i am loading the parameters by using the "rosparam load" command, and after i go the folder that i have compiled my distribution of "move_base" and executing the binary by giving 2 more arguments(necessary for my changes into the code). The problem is that when i am executing the binary it says that it loads the parameters (-v : verbose mode) but during the move_base execution the parameters that have been loaded are **not** taken into account.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58849/rosparam-load-into-shell-script/) by [kostasof](https://answers.ros.org/users/4493/kostasof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a direct answer to your question as I am not sure what's going wrong with your approach. I suspect some namespacing issue in play here. Anyway here are 2 alternative solutions for what you're trying to do using launch files:

1. The roslaunch syntax allows for
   supplying custom arguments to your
   binary. See the args attribute
   inside the node element here:
   http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node
2. You can convert your binary
   arguments to ROS parameters, and add
   appropriate parameters to your
   launch file. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you bring up the move_base node,  you should print the full parameter listing using `rosparam list` or `rosparam dump`.  This often helps uncover issues where parameters are loaded into the wrong namespace.

In this case, it looks to me like you might be loading your parameters into the "root" namespace (e.g. "/local_costmap").  According to the move_base [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base), these parameters should instead be specified in the node's private namespace (e.g. "/move_base/local_costmap").

---

Also, have you considered using a launch file to load the parameters and run the node?  That would be the normal way this is done in ROS.  This automatically loads the parameter files and places the parameters in the node's private namespace.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="path_file" default="/home/kostasof/Desktop/test_420/Move_Base.xml"/>
  <arg name="cfg_path" value="~/ros_stacks_sc/navigation_kostas/cfg_rafa"/>

  <node name="move_base" pkg="move_base" type="move_base" args="$(arg path_file) wlan0">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg cfg_path)/costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg cfg_path)/costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="local_costmap"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg cfg_path)/base_global_planner_params.yaml"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg cfg_path)/base_local_planner_params.yaml"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$arg cfg_path)/global_costmap_params.yaml"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$arg cfg_path)/local_costmap_params.yaml"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

*Note: in order to use your version of move_base in place of the standard system package, make sure your home-dir is listed in $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH before the default system path.*

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1